# Sharing PyJulia instance across multiple sub-processes in an application

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, julia

I have an application that spawns multiple sub-processes. I use a Julia package (DiffEq.jl) in each of the sub-processes (through diffeqpy). However, each sub-process is creating it's Julia instance, which adds overheads both in terms of initialization time and memory.

I want to create a single PyJulia process and share it across multiple sub-processes so that DiffEq.jl will only be imported once. Any insights on how to do this would be very helpful.

Comment: I would use Genie.jl and expose DiffEq.jl functionality via a RESTful API. Or use Flask with diffeqpy and allow python processes to connect. My guess is that this is the only option that will work in your scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a web application. Another solution would be great.

Comment: how is that relevant whether it is a web application or not? this is just perhaps the simplest way for inter-process communication. Other possible approaches are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication   and since you want ta have many Pythons-to-one-Julia you will need to pick something